# Unable to change global variable in React Native, are they read-only?

Tags: react-native, global-variables

I am having the most difficult and frustrating time changing a 'global' variable in React Native.  I am new to the language however this should be far simpler than it evidently is.  It seems as if 'global' variables are 'read only' and cannot be changed...but I find that impossible to believe.  Is it related to usage of React Navigation?  Here is some code.  First I create a .js file to hold my 'global' variable object:

```
//'globals.js'

module.exports = {
 STATUS: 'false',
};
```

Now my main code in 'app.js':

```
//'app.js'

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

GLOBAL = require('./globals');  //import the 'global' object and assign name

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {

 return (
  <>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'    }}>
      <Text>Passed GLOBAL: {JSON.stringify(GLOBAL.STATUS)}</Text>  //indicates 'false'...as it should when running for the first time...
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
 {GLOBAL.STATUS === 'false' ? (
        <Button
          title="Go to Login"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}
        />
      ) : (
        <Button title="Do Stuff" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('StuffScreen')} />
      )}
  </>
 );

}

function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
//do stuff to login here...
var _test = 'dwarves';
GLOBAL.STATUS = _test;

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'    }}>
      <Text>Stuff Screen</Text>
      <Text>Set Global: {JSON.stringify(GLOBAL.STATUS)}</Text>  //still indicates 'false' even after changing value, should be 'dwarves'...WHY????
      <Button title="Go to Home" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')} />
    </View>
  );
}

function StuffScreen({ navigation }) {
//do stuff here...
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Stuff" component={StuffScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

can somebody explain why the 'GLOBAL.STATUS' value is NOT passed to the 'Home' screen when changed in another function...??? As a global variable this should be the case, however I am finding it impossible to achieve.  Thank you for any suggestions on what I am not understanding about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple one, changing the value of any variable that is not part of some sort of state or props does not cause the React tree to re-render.

The variable is being changed but your `HomeScreen` component never gets notified of that change and this is by design. Can you imagine the performance issues that we would be having if every variable assignment triggered re-renders?

I suggest you look into the [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API, it allows you to expose values to all your components as well as notifying the necessary components when the values change.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will take a look at the 'Context' API to attempt to resolve.